# Including a task with specified variables (Ansible)

Tags: ansible

I'm just starting to learn ansible. I've set up a test repository [here](https://github.com/nfarrar/crib2/tree/master/ansible).

I'm trying to include a task, and pass it a message as a variable that should be 'printed' by the task. My playbook (site.yml) is structured like this:

```
- name:  default playbook
  tasks:
    - { include: tasks/timestamp.yml, themsg='starting tasks' }
```

And `tasks/timestamp.yml` is:

```
---
- debug: msg="{{ themsg }} ' @ ' {{ ansible_date_time['time'] }}."
```

When I run this with `ansible-playbook site.yml` I get the error:

```
TASK: [debug msg="{{ themsg }} 'current time:' {{     ansible_date_time['time'] }}."] *** fatal: [localhost] => One or more undefined variables: 'themsg' is undefined
```

I've been using the [official documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html) as a reference, and it seems like this should work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be that you need to add a conditional when this is called?

Comment: I have no idea. First go at learning ansible. This seems identical to the example from the official docs.

Comment: I looked through the documentation and it seems that the examples use something similar when a conditional is being used (not that that will solve the problem since it seems like it is complaining about a variable)

Comment: please list how you are running this (`ansible ...`) and the version of Ansible you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something *slightly* out-of-the-ordinary (including tasks, instead of using roles, from a playbook) and were caught up by some common syntactical errors.

You found the right documentation; it gives the following for including a task file:

```
- include: wordpress.yml wp_user=timmy
- { include: wordpress.yml, wp_user: timmy, ssh_keys: [ 'keys/one.txt', 'keys/two.txt' ] }
```

Unfortunately you combined those:

```
- { include: tasks/timestamp.yml, themsg='starting tasks' }
```

Here's how to get out of the jam. Either of these will work:

```
- { include: tasks/timestamp.yml, themsg: 'starting tasks' }
- include: tasks/timestamp.yml themsg='starting tasks'
```

In the first example I've changed `=` to a colon. In the second example I've removed the braces and removed the comma.

It's really easy to upgrade this "task include" to a "role include". Move `tasks/timestamp.yml` to `roles/timestamp/tasks/main.yml`, then include this as a role instead of a task:

```
roles:
  - { role: timestamp, themsg: "starting tasks" }
```

You gain some sanity with that- some portability, hooks with prerequisites and handlers, etc.

Comment: Thanks, super helpful. :) I'm still trying to figure out the basics. My main.yml has a couple of defined roles 'homebrew' & 'apt' right now - homebrew installs homebrew packages *if* the os is Darwin, and apt *if* it's Ubuntu. It seems like those were proper entities for 'roles' but displaying a debugging message with a timestamp was more of a 'task' than a 'role'. What I've noticed now though is that the tasks from main.yml only run if no roles are defined ...

Comment: Can you make a small test case that shows that tasks don't run when there are roles? I just ran two "include" tasks (as above) and one "role" task (as above), all three work.

Comment: Sorry - so what was actually happening is my role had an error in it. Once I fixed the error in the role, I saw that the task runs *after* the role, even though it's listed in the playbook *before* the role. Here's the example: https://github.com/nfarrar/crib2/tree/master/ansible. I'm starting to think I'm going about this all wrong, trying to create a task to display debugging information at runtime. The logging information is frustratingly sparse (especially when just getting started).

Comment: aha! Yeah, it's all about ordering, and that stage of YML is a dict/hash, so order doesn't actually help (it isn't documented, either). You may want to use `pre_tasks` and `post_tasks`. I use those even though almost everything is role-based.